# Equivalent of Windsor Depends on in structureMap

Tags: castle-windsor, structuremap

How to inject the Construtor Arguments dynamically in the structureMap Something like Windsor Dependson where i can Pass all the Property[] to it.. Even AutoFac has Resolveparamter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not well versed in either AutoFac or Windsor, but after looking at examples of each I think you're after this structure map construct for injecting parameters:

```
For<IMyType>.Use<MyType>.Ctor<string>("parameterName").Is("parameterValue");
```